# How can I replace the most popular cuss words with words which don't sound overly deliberately euphemistic and outright childish?

Tags: word-choice, offensive-language, euphemisms

It's not that I curse a lot, even when I'm angry, but I don't particularly like the origin of certain, particularly the most popular English ones, cuss words, so I am trying to stop using them altogether. However, in my endeavour to do this I have encountered many an obstacle: too many, virtually all in fact, of the most popular English cuss words sound too purposely euphemistic or childish, e.g. instead of "fuck", some people recommend "fudge"; instead of "shit" or "shite" or whatever, words like "snap" or "shoot" are recommended; or instead of "asshole" or "asswipe" words like "dog-do" may be recommended according to certain sources.

I want words which still really express my anger, upset, frustration, suprise, etc., at something or someone or whatever without lapsing into the use of cuss words.

Comment: Using word X or non-word Y as a cuss in place of taboo word Z is still cussing, and perhaps morally more reprehensible, as it adds attempted cover-up.

Comment: Because I don't like blasphemy or obscenity, I sometimes use "Oh, rats!" as an expletive. Surely you can think of some word with unpleasant connotations that it might satisfy you to use?

Comment: "Oh, my stars and garters!" is good for variety. Many good replacements are to be found in works of fiction. Authors seem to enjoy working hard to find relatively inoffensive ways to say offensive things. Real world speech? Not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [minced oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) on Wikipedia:

> A **minced oath** is a euphemistic expression formed by misspelling, mispronouncing, or replacing a part of a profane, blasphemous, or taboo term to reduce the original term's objectionable characteristics. Some examples include "gosh" (for God), "crumbs" (for Christ), "crikey" (for Christ kill me), "for crying out loud" (for Christ's sake), "darn" or "dang" (for damn), "doggone" or "gosh darn" (for goddamn), "cor blimey" (for "God blind me"), "heck" (for hell), "gee", "jeez", "jeepers", or "Jiminy Cricket" (for Jesus Christ), "feck". "fudge", "frick", "fork", "flip" or "eff" (for fuck).

Note I am not saying how accurate the above examples are, I'm merely quoting directly from Wikipedia.

Wiktionary also has some examples of [minced oaths](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minced_oath).

> - *cheese and rice* for *Jesus Christ*
> - *gosh* for *God*
> - *geez* for *Jesus*

etc.

See also: "Homer says 'Fiddle dee dee'" on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rlv-T6mKVH8

Answer (score 0):

Finding synonyms for common cuss words is the wrong approach. Substituting *fudge* for *fuck* is juvenile and not always valid. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxpV8D8K9JI is a fun humor video which is mostly about the many uses of *fuck*. *Fuck* is probably the most versatile cuss word, but all the common cuss words have very wide ranges of meanings.

Rather than replacing words, you'll need to replace usages.

- For an exclamation of frustration, instead of *Fuck!* or *Dammit!*, try *Drat!* or *Dash it all!*
- For an exclamation of impressed awe, instead of *Oh, shit!*, try *Oh, wow!*
- For sex, instead of *fuck*, try *sleep with* or *screw*.
- For sending someone away, instead of *Fuck off!*, try *Begone!*.

Unfortunately, I do not have the patience to extend this list very far. Such a list must exist inside you to express all the concepts we have with cuss words without using those words. You can't say, "They were late to the party because they were begone-ing" or "I am tired of your face! Oh wow!". You really need to handle the different uses case-by-case.